# MVC framework with Wordpress frontpage

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess, model-view-controller

I'm using the [Huge MVC framewrok](https://github.com/panique/huge). My app is a Portfolio SaaS which runs on `domain.com` and users have subdomains `user.domain.com` to load their portfolios.

In my IndexController I check for subdomain or the www version of the site.

```
    $urlParts = explode('.', $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']);

    if ( count($urlParts) > 2 && $urlParts[0] !== 'www' ) {
        //...//
        $this->View->twig( $data , $theme);
    }
    else {
        //"No Subdomain Found. Load Wordpress
    }
```

My question is how do I use Wordpress for the frontpage of the SaaS yet keep all the MVC routes still working?

For example:

`www.domain.com/edit/portraits/85` is an MVC route for editing a gallery but

`www.domain.com/post-title` is a Wordpress link (permalink)

I just need general direction: should I look into .htaccess or VirtualHost or just PHP.

Comment: Should `www.domain.com` point to WordPress? If not, you could install WordPress in a subdirectory `blog` of the public directory of your server. So the WP home page would point to `www.domain.com/blog`

Comment: www.domain.com should be the wordpress homepage. It would be really easy on a sub-directory like /blog :)

Comment: I'd clearly separate both installations and use the web server configuration to configure the specific URLs to be handled by specific things. That means, you list out all patterns of URLs you have and direct them to your Wordpress installation or your MVC installation. Remember that your file structure and your URL structure don't necessary have to correspond 1:1, this is all part of the web server configuration. If you're going to mix two different pieces of software together, you need to be diligent and detailed about that configuration.

Comment: @decaze Thanks a lot. I end up doing exactly that and I don't regret it. I now have two distinct folders `wordpress` and `app` and used VirtualHost to direct the mvc routes to `app` and everything else to `wordpress`. Much cleaner than what I was doing.